# React-native + mobx how the Index.js should look like

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

im trying to integrate Mobx(I´m new to Mobx to be honest) to my existing react-native project and one big question I have is how should the indexfile look like?

mine is looking now like this:

#### Index.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './../App/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName', () => App);
```

but some tutorials told me that it should look like this:

#### Index.js:

```
 {a bunch of imports here...}
 ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
     <App />
   </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

but i dont get the second one running.

so my question is how should the index.js look like?

Comment: what's the code for your store

Comment: I don't see why this should be relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AppRegistry.registerComponent` accepts a function which returns a component, so it should work if you have that component render the Provider.

```
const Root = () => (
  <Provider {...stores}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName', () => Root)
```

Comment: man you really saved my day! may i ask how did you get to this solution? or mabe give me some advise wehre I could learn things like that for further problems I will encounter.

Comment: Well, the only requirement was having the app component wrapped in a provider, and if you understand what each part of the index file is actually doing, then you'll realize there are plenty of ways to accomplish that. [Since the docs for the `registerComponent` function are kind of bare,](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry#registercomponent) I had to make sort of an educated guess on how it works